# How to unsubscribe from collection changes in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to unsubscribe from a change listener in Firestore, but am unable to get it to work.

According to the Firebase documentation you need to call the onSnapshot() method to stop listening. What am I missing?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

This is the hook that calls the subscribe/unsubscribe action creators:

```
useEffect(() => {
  subscribe()
  return () => {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}, [])
```

And here are the subscribe/unsubscribe action creators:

```
export const subscribe = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {    
    const items = db.collection('items')

    items.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((item) =>  item.data())

      dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING', payload: data })
    })
  }
}

export const unsubscribe = () => {
  const items = db.collection('items')

  const unsubscribe = () => items.onSnapshot(() => {})

  unsubscribe()
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example in `unsubscribe` action you create another listener and immediately unsubscribe from it, so it doesn't affect the listener in `subscribe` action.

```
export const subscribe = (setUnsubscribe) => {
  return (dispatch) => {    
    const items = db.collection('items')

    const unsubscribe = items.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((item) =>  item.data())
      dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING', payload: data })
    });

    setUnsubscribe(unsubcsribe);
  }
}


// Component

useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe = () => {};
  subscribe((func) => { unsubscribe = func });
  return () => unsubscribe();
}, [])
```

Comment: What if you have multiple listeners in your subscribe?